# Logarithmic scale for a learning curve

Tags: python, deep-learning, plotting, validation, loss

I'm plotting the learning curve with Python with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

# Increase the plot size and font size.
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,6)
plt.plot(lst, 'r')

plt.legend(["Validation Loss"])
# Label the plot.
plt.title("RNN deltat")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
```

The curve looks like this:
[image]

The lecturer said better try it on a logarithmic scale. Can you please help to apply the logarithm here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited to the stackoverflow stackexchange. To change the y-axis from a linear scale to a logarithmic scale you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) function using `"log"` as the argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.yscale("log")
```